# Mockmultipart pdf in python

Tags: multipart, python-bytearray, python-pdfreader

Mockmultipart is used to parse the file from multiparty form, do we have any in python to do mockmultipart and convert the file to multipart and bytearray ?

I tried with email multipart and urllib , but those are working as expected.

I have a set of pdf in zip archive which has to be converted to multipart and then to bytearray, please share your comments